# How can i merge similar cells together in excel?

Tags: excel

Im working with a a dataset in excel and Im trying to create make a graph or chart about crime and how many times it has been commited. However i have realised i have too many types of crime (167) and i need to shorten it down to be able to visualize the data in a simple format. I see that large amount of the crimes are similar and it would be a good idea to merge them. For example

```
BATTERY - SIMPLE ASSAULT    73570
BATTERY FIREMAN 19
BATTERY ON A FIREFIGHTER    107
BATTERY POLICE  1643
BATTERY WITH SEXUAL CONTACT 3821
```

So i could merge these two columuns and 5 rows into  one row.

So the end result would be

```
 Battery : 79160
```

Is there any way be able automatically do that in excel? If not is there any way i can chart the data in its current format with the large amount of different crimes into a type of graph?

Comment: This looks like you would want to query based on your information into a new sheet.  that way you could sum a column given the matching of another column.

Comment: Would it always be the first word on which you would combine.  You will need to have a hard rule by which excel can look at the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Sumif function with wildcards to summarise your data. Assuming your list is in column A and your values are in column B, you can put the following into another cell:

```
=SUMIF($A1:$A100,"*Battery*",$B1:$B100)
```

The construction `"*Battery*"` will trigger on all cells that contain the word "Battery". If you wanted, you could also create a list of the key words you want to use, and use references to them in your formula. Say you put your full list on Sheet1 in columns A and B, then your category list in column D, and your formula in column E; the formula might look like this:

```
=Sumif($A$1:$A$100,"*" & $D1 & "*",$B$1:$B$100)
```

The & operator combines two text strings, so `"*" & $D1 & "*"` produces whatever word is in cell D1 with a leading and trailing wildcard.

[image: Example]